# Как можно сделать подсказчик для поля ввода, точности, как в Гугл?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, mysqli

Нужно реализовать подсказчик для поля ввода, точности, как в Гугл.
Например. Я в поле ввода input ввожу "тип", а мне выдается самый популярный список слов и фраз ("типография", "типография москва", ...).

Есть ли где-то база популярных слов и фраз гугл, которая постоянно обновляется, в открытом доступе?
Может уже существует такая функция, которая выдаст нам нужный результат?
Или только прийдется динамично парсить сайт гугл и подтягивать список фраз ?

Comment: что за подсказчик точности? Если это уже сделано в Гугл, значит это можно сделать

Comment: >'как в Гугл без своей базы слов и фраз'
нет, иначе откуда вы будите брать слова и фразы?

Comment: Можно ли динамично подтягивать  список слов и фраз из гугла, к себе на сайт

Comment: _Можно ли динамично подтягивать этот список, к себе на сайт._ - подтягивать откуда?

Comment: Если сможете динамично парсить гугл и он вас не забанит - озолотитесь

Comment: Не факт. Я теперь зашла в тупик. А Вы парсили когда-то сайты динамично. Что еще можете посоветовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучше всего этот список брать у самого Google. cURL-ом дергаете данные с
    http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=firefox&client=firefox&hl=en-US&q=KEYWORD 
(где KEYWORD - ваша часть строки) и получаете то, что нужно в формате json

Comment: Я не совсем поняла, что это за строчка кода? На каком языке написано? Как это мне можно использовать.Может я еще могу что-то почитать?

Comment: По этой ссылке можно получить подсказки Google в формате json по любой строке (слово KEYWORD меняете на любую свою строку). Полученный результат можно с помощью json_decode() перевести в массив и вывести где угодно и как угодно.

Comment: Большое спасибо)) Но оно не совсем выводит, то что выводит google.com.ua или google.ru ( Может вы что-то знаете,что можно поправить?

Comment: Попробуйте в параметрах вместо en-US поставить ru-RU

Comment: Да, я ставила и ua - ставила, и chrome ставила, все равно, что-то не получается именно такой же самый вывод как в гугл.

Comment: Это и есть google. Возможно, разность выдачи обусловлена поведенческим фактором.

Comment: Я теперь зашла в тупик. Вы можете еще что-то посоветовать?

Comment: Ну а что тут посоветовать? Если выдача http://suggestqueries.google.com и "гугла в браузере" отличается, то скорее всего Гугл для формирования списка подсказок использует ПФ. И ничего с этим не поделать. А что, неужели это так критично, что выдача отличается? Изначально вопрос же был о некоей базе популярных слов, которая обновляется.  У http://suggestqueries.google.com именно она и есть.

Comment: Дело в том что мне нужна база именно которую мне выдает https://www.google.com (. А что вы скажите насчет динамичного парсинга сайта?

Comment: И еще в добавок я не могу искать по двум словам мне выдает ошибку =( Warning: file_get_contents(http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=chrome&client=chrome&hl=ua-US&q=тип кр): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request

Comment: Динамичный парсинг гугла - это однозначный бан с его стороны. И гугл сделает это довольно быстро.

Comment: По поводу двух слов - примените к запросу функцию url_encode перед отправкой